# Create new list after every second element while iterating over an array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

While iterating over an array to create LI nodes, UL should be close after every second LI to generate following HTML structure

**Required Output**

```
<ul class="bt-zone-pair">
    <li class="bt-zone">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Team <span>A</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="bt-zone">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Team <span>B</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="bt-zone-pair">
    <li class="bt-zone">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Team <span>C</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="bt-zone">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Team <span>D</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/o8gL3L3o/

**JavaScript**

```
var btTeams = ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team E', 'Team F', 'Team G', 'Team H'];

var domFragmentTeams = "";
var destinationCol = $('.bt-col1');

// create Teams in column 1
$.each(btTeams, function( intIndex, objValue ){
    var listItemWrapper = destinationCol.append(
      $('<ul class="bt-zone-pair"></ul>')
    );

    listItemWrapper.append(
      $('<li class="bt-zone"><a href="javscript:void(0)">' + objValue + "</a></li>")
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Also I'm not sure, but I guess is not good to append elements in loop. You can create entire list and perform a bulk operation.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/o8gL3L3o/12/).

#### .each Code

```
// Define a variable outside so you can append string to it
var _html = "";

$.each(btTeams, function(intIndex, objValue) {
  // For odd values, add start tags.
  if ((intIndex + 1) % 2 !== 0) {
    _html += '<ul class="bt-zone-pair">';
  }
  
  // Add li for all cases
  _html += '<li class="bt-zone"><a href="javscript:void(0)">' + 
    objValue + "</a></li>";

  // Add end tag for even cases
  if ((intIndex + 1) % 2 === 0) {
    _html += "</ul>"
  }
});

// Append constructed HTML
destinationCol.append(_html);
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me and you are absolutely right about not appending elements inside loop [time for me to re-cap the basics] :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the % operator (Modulus (division remainder)) in order to use code only every OTHER iteration.

```
var btTeams = ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team E', 'Team F', 'Team G', 'Team H'];

var domFragmentTeams = "";
var destinationCol = $('.bt-col1');

// create Teams in column 1
$.each(btTeams, function( intIndex, objValue ){
    var listItemWrapper = destinationCol;
    if(intIndex%2 ==0) {
      destinationCol.append(
          $('<ul class="bt-zone-pair"></ul>')
      );
    }
      listItemWrapper.append(
          $('<li class="bt-zone"><a href="javscript:void(0)">' + objValue + "</a></li>")
      );

  }
);
```